# Angular 2: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined onclick of submit

Tags: node.js, mongoose, angular2-routing

I'm trying to save a product to mongoose and instead of subscribe i have used then in my component, why do i get:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

**component.ts**

```
//Confirm Create before save to table function
onCreateConfirm(event) {
if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to create?')) {
  //console.log(this.selectedObject)
  this.productService.productSave(event.newData, this.selectedObject).then(data => {
    //if (data.success) {
      //console.log('success data')
      this.flashMessage.show('Product successfully added', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
      this.router.navigate(['/category-items']);
    } , (err) => {
      //console.log('failure data...')
      this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
      this.router.navigate(['/category-items']);

  });
  event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
} else {
  //console.log('not saving...')
  event.confirm.reject();
}
}
```

**service.ts**

```
//Save new Product
 productSave(products, categoryId) {

let prodDet = {
  catId: categoryId,
  productDetail: products
}

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.post(this.domain + 'products/add', { prodDet }, { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res);
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

**In node js product.js**

```
    Products.addProduct(newProduct, (err, products) => {
if(err){
  res.json({success: false, msg:'Product unable to add :('});
} else {
  res.json({success: true, msg:'Products successfuly added!!'});
 }
 });
});
```

I logged the response: i get product unable to add from node js product.js

Comment: console.log the response... are you sure there is a response?

Comment: In product.js in the if(err) branch make a console.log(err); to see, which error you have. I assume as long as the error in Products.addProduct is not fixed, it won't work.